# write an array to file 25 elements at a time

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable length array (xml) from which I want to extract the details and then write the contents of each element to a file containing 25 elements at a time, until all elements have been processed.
I'm OK with the reading and writing part but my mind is blank as to how to correctly split it into blocks.

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
$dataToWrite = $dataToWrite . $element;
}
fwrite($file, $dataToWrite)
```

but how do I iterate 25 elements at a time?
I've been trying with simple code (below) but this seems a "bodge job" to me. Is there a cleaner, more robust solution?

```
    <?php
$index= 0;
$colours=array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown","pink","orange","light blue","black","white","purple","mauve","cyan","brown","indigo","scarlet");
$temp = array_chunk($colours, 2, true);
$count = count($temp);
while ($index<$count){
    $dataToWrite = "";
    foreach ($temp[$index] as $element){
        $dataToWrite = $dataToWrite . $element;
    };
    $index++;
    echo "header " . $dataToWrite . " footer" . "<br>";
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way using you original block of code:

- Change the **foreach** loop to a **for** loop (to get the number of items in the array use **count**)
- In the for loop have an if statement that checks to see if the value of your iterator variable mod 25 is equal to 0, if it is write out your data and clear the dataToWrite variable
- Also make sure to write out your data after your loop is done as well just in case there was some extra data left that wasn't written out inside the loop.

Comment: Could you provide an example please using the original code?

Comment: Just to clarify each "string" (essentially an item from a feed) is composed of say 20 "substrings" (info on the item) and I want to put <>25 of these items in each file. I can get the info and process etc but I'm struggling for a clean robust solution for writing in blocks instead of all at one time. thanks

Comment: Hi Sharon, is there something you are confused about in my original suggestion? If it's how to use a for loop instead of a foreach loop, this site will help: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/5/3/0

Comment: Hi Kijow, I just had a mental block on this. foreach ($xml->property as $property) 
//set up variables and concat
$summaryPageData = $summaryPageData .$variables
 if (($i++ % $page_size == 0) && (!$first_time )) {
  //create a new page 
  $fh = fopen($pageName, 'w'); // or die("error");
  $top_section =”…..";
  $bottom_section = "<?php include(\"../footer.php\"); ?>";
  $dataToWrite = $top_section . $summaryPageData .  $bottom_section;
  fwrite($fh, $dataToWrite)
  $dataToWrite = "";
  $summaryPageData = "";
     }
 $first_time = false;
}
// end
?> now I just have the extra data issue to solve

Comment: Hi Sharon, if I am understanding your code correctly, you just need to repeat the following after your loop exits:
   
$dataToWrite = $top_section . $summaryPageData . $bottom_section; 
fwrite($fh, $dataToWrite);

Comment: Also, this line $fh = fopen($pageName, 'w'); probably should not be in your loop, as you only need to open it once. Unless you are wanting to open and close it each time then make sure you close it.

Comment: There is a lot of code missing but essentially I make a string which creates the centre content of a web page. I want to write <>20 objects in this centre part so that's what the if() does. Then I add an header and footer and write it. But the if doesn't "fire" on the last iteration so I am left with unwritten data. You are right about fopen() but I worked so I left it. I had other problems <g>. Thanks

Comment: See my previous post about $dataToWrite. You are not left with unwritten data if you add those two lines after your loop ends.

Comment: I can't. "top section" is my header + a bit extra, "summaryPageData" is the dynamic content and "bottom_section" my footer + a bit that only needs writing once. If I duplicated that line I would get two headers and two footers. Perhaps if add an or ($last_time) to the if. I'll have a go.

Comment: Yes, you can figure out what your last time will be by dividing the number of total entries (array count) by 25.